# Snowflake: Hovering Over Table Name Shows Created Date How to Add Modified Date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, if I hover over a database object, it shows me the created date for a table. Is there a way to modified the database object view to also include last modified date?

Comment: I removed the 'sql` tag - this questions seems related to the UI only?

Comment: Correct, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know if there is a setting to enable showing last modified date in the UI, the answer is no. There is no settings for it.

As you know last modified date of the table is updated with both DDL and DML operations. This could be the reason that it's not shown with the creation date (to prevent misunderstanding like it's the last DDL time).

Answer (score 0):

There's not an option to display that in the UI, but you can run this SQL to get an ***approximation*** of the last time a table changed. The time returns in UTC:

```
create or replace function APPROXIMATE_LAST_MODIFIED(TABLENAME string)
returns timestamp
language sql
as
$$
    dateadd('ms', SYSTEM$LAST_CHANGE_COMMIT_TIME( TABLENAME ),'1970-01-01')
$$;

select approximate_last_modified('MY_TABLE');
```

You can also send it the fully-qualified object name `"MY_DB"."MY_SCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"`.